# Range Selection Using Excel Macro

Tags: excel, range, selection, vba

```
  A      B        C

123455  XXX     99999
123456  XX      100000
123457  XXX     100001
174564  XXXX    100002
184567          100003
194570          100004
204573          100005
214576          100006
224579          100007
                100008
```

I would like to write a macro for selecting a range using `<ctrl> + <down arrow>`

The process should be like this

1. Select cell A1
2. Select a Range with `<shift> + <ctrl> + <page down>`
3. Aelect cell A1 without cancelling the range selection (using `<ctrl>`)
4. `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select`
5. Then range select from C1 to C9 with `<shift> + <ctrl> + <page down>` then `<shift> + <up arrow>`

Following those steps in my example data, 224579 and 100007 are selected at same row, 100008 is not selected.

I want to select the range between A1 to A9 also C1 to C9, but I want the macro to do this without defining a range like A1 and A9, because the range will probably change like A1 will change to A5 after some alterations. So, I want the macro to adapt and grab the numbers accordingly.

Comment: For reference to anyone else coming upon this question, usign the Macro Recorder built in to Office can make this kind of solution very easy to find yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if A1 is the active cell.

```
Union(Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)), Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2))).Select
```

Comment: I want to select the range between A1 to A9 also C1 to C9  . But i want macro to do this without range defining like A1 and A9 because probably the range will change like A1 will change to A5 after some alterations so i want Macro to adapt and grab the numbers accordingly

Comment: @eggplant_parm thanks but that will choose the whole range including B column. I don't want to select that column.

Comment: @user768199 This will only select columns A and C.

Comment: Oh yes eggplant_parm you have changed the code :) What if i want to add the E column again till the same row for example ?  A  C  E selected until the same row ?

Comment: @user768199 You can add another range inside the union() with the offsets set to 4 instead of 2.

Comment: @eggplant_parm yes but that only selects A and E column, not C

Comment: @user768199 You have to add third range, not just change the second one: Union(Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)), Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2)), Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4), ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4))).Select

Comment: Thanks very much eggplant_parm, i will solve this on my own afterwards =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but do you want this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Static self_protect As Boolean

  If self_protect Then Exit Sub

  self_protect = True
  Set Target = Target.Areas(1)
  Application.Union(Target, Target.Offset(0, 2)).Select
  self_protect = False
End Sub
```

Paste the code into a worksheet code module and select a range on the sheet.

Comment: I dont understand ?  I copy and pasted this code to Macro Module  then click run   it open the classic macro run/ create / cancel window with none of the buttons were active (except Cancel)

Comment: @user768199 Copy into a *worksheet code module* (the code module named after the worksheet you want the code to work on), not a macro module. You don't have to explicitly run it. Just select a range on that sheet.

Comment: WOW. How can i do this in Macro ? Also if i want to add more columns like 4th and 6th column to the selection ?