# Can't run sub again after Exit Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I ran the below code (trying to ensure any text entered in a range was in upper case only) which ran fine. However I then deleted data from a range of cells and it then exited the sub and I now can't get it running again, can anyone help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("O5:Q1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = UCase(Target)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You passed the entire `Target.Value` array to `UCase`, that caused a Type mismatch, the execution stopped at that line and `Application.EnableEvents = True` never executed. Execute it manually from the Immediate window. An example of why one should [not use global state to manage a local problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873). Use a [static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114646/11683) to prevent the reentrance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to comment, here's how to fix that:

```
For Each c In Target
    c = UCase(c)
Next
```

Instead of `Target = UCase(Target)`

You need to loop through all cells in afected range.

Comment: Um... No, that does not fix it.

Comment: Did you test it when `Target` is more than one cell?

Comment: @GSerg Yes, I did

Comment: No, you didn't. `UCase` cannot accept an array. And if it could, the OP's code would work just fine.

Comment: @GSerg How can we cause `Target` to be an array?

Comment: By editing several cells at once. The OP specifically said they cleared a bunch of cells (by selecting them all and pressing Delete).

Comment: @GSerg Ahh i get it now... Edited an answer ;)